# Passing parameter to controller from route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**THIS IS A QUESTION FOR LARAVEL 3**

Given the following route

```
Route::get('groups/(:any)', array('as' => 'group', 'uses' => 'groups@show'));
```

And the URL I would like to use,

```
http://www.example.com/groups/1
```

I would like to be able to use the `(:any)` value in my controller.

My controller looks like

```
class Groups_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_show($groupID) {
        return 'I am group id ' . $groupID;
    }  


}
```

How is this possible to do?  I have tried a few things including the following

```
Route::get('groups/(:any)', array('as' => 'group', 'uses' => 'groups@show((:1))'));
```

but it did not work.

**UPDATE**

Anytime I try to pass in the arguments as show above i get a 404 error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was just doing this and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong until I realized the parameter I was passing has forward slashes in it.

Comment: @dardub see update.  and what do you mean by your second comment.  Example?

Comment: I was passing an encrypted string that looked like http://www.example.com/groups/h39rcqwfc/3cr30ficwfcw==

Comment: The first route you showed looks right to me.

Comment: @dardub The first route works... but I want to use the `1` in the controller/model so i can get group 1 from the database.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need anything special for adding paramaters. Just like you had it.

```
Route::get('groups/(:any)', array('as' => 'group', 'uses' => 'groups@show'));


class Groups_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;    

    public function get_show($groupID) {
        return 'I am group id ' . $groupID;
    }  


}
```

Comment: This is an absurd,  that this simple example (that parameters are passed to action function as arguments) isn't included in docs.

Comment: @MārtiņšBriedis, the Laravel docs are a closed loop of being an excellent reference for somebody who knows everything about Laravel except the thing they are looking up.

Comment: It's an open source project, you can fork/edit the docs and add what you think is missing. https://github.com/laravel/docs

Comment: @dwenaus - that's true and awesome, but it only works after you have discovered what it is that you don't know...  which isn't in the docs. Lots of googling and eliminating old solutions which are no longer valid or best practice. Lots of bad advice from other lost souls trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 30):

This is what you need in 1 line of code.

`Route::get('/groups/{groupId}', 'GroupsController@getShow');`

Suggestion: Use CamelCase as opposed to underscores, try & follow [PSR-* guidelines](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md).

Hope it helps.

Comment: By `public function getShow($groupId){  }` it worked. Also to reduce possibility of errors use browser

Answer (score 11):

You can add them like this

```
  Route::get('company/{name}', 'PublicareaController@companydetails');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    $ php artisan route:list
  +--------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+--    -----------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------  ---+
  | Domain | Method                         | URI                        |  Name              | Action                                             |    Middleware |
  +--------+--------------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
  |        | GET|HEAD                       | /                          |                           
  |        | GET                            | campaign/showtakeup/{id}   | showtakeup         | App\Http\Controllers\campaignController@showtakeup | auth       |     |
```

routes.php

```
  Route::get('campaign/showtakeup/{id}', ['uses' =>'campaignController@showtakeup'])->name('showtakeup');
```

campaign.showtakeup.blade.php

```
 @foreach($campaign as $campaigns)


   //route parameters; you may pass them as the second argument to the method:

   <a href="{{route('showtakeup', ['id' => $campaigns->id])}}">{{ $campaigns->name }}</a>




            @endforeach
```

Hope this solves your problem.
Thanks