# I want to capture the id of this route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-7

I want to capture the ID of the route where I am at this moment that is the show route but I want to capture that id where I am and send them to another controller,

I explain in the URL user / {id} = user / 1 or user / 2 and so I want to capture that id that is shown in this view and thus pass it to another controller to be able to perform an inserted database

```
Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@show')->name('user.show');
http://localhost:8000/user/1
```

and I want to pass it to this driver `StudentController` that ID

```
public function getID()
{
     \DB::table('students')->insert([
                        [
                            'name' => $row->name, 
                            'project_id' => 1//request()->route('project.show',$item->id)


                        ]
                    ]);
}
```

Comment: The above would call the method `show()` on your controller class `UserController`. Where does the `getID()` come into play and what is the actual issue? This question is very unclear. Please show us _all_ the relevant code and explain what you're trying to do and the issue step by step.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameter to controller from route in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647424/passing-parameter-to-controller-from-route-in-laravel)

Comment: @Froxz please look at the first thing written in your suggested dupe, it is for L3.

Comment: @Script47 nothing changed since then, with how you pass paramter from route to controller...

Comment: Why you want use getID ? 
When you access `http://localhost:8000/user/1`, the Router, send to `Usercontroller@show` the {id} in the show method.

Comment: I want it is to call that show its id to another independent controller and to be able to do an insert according to that id

Comment: You can store it into a Session, or call the method with one parameter

Answer (score 3):

You need to add in your "show" method the ID .

Like this :

```
public function show ($id)
{
   // Do your stuff
}
```

And when calling your route, dont forget to pass the id into route.

```
route('user.show', ['id' => $id]);
```

See this documentation, is anonymous function, but it's the same concept

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Your Route should look like, to return the `id` value when your route is used :

```
Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@show', function ($id) {
    return $id;
});
```

Then you can access it in your function like :

```
$request->route('id');
```

Comment: Explain why you have a callback in the route?

Comment: To return the value of the parameter when the route is called so it can be accessed by the the middleware or controller

Comment: @pr1nc3 it can be accessed in the controller without the callback. Your answer just adds redundant code.

Comment: I used it like that in previous projects of mine since i read it in the laravel official documentation and also laracast shows it that way, but i assume you are right. Thanks for pointing out will try it your way as seems more "clear" without the callback of course